# How to change variable or values on the fly with Jmeter based on user input?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I'm using `JMeter` to test a `Web OE` site where the user can select a product then select a width, height, color and other options. Based on the width and height a different price is returned.

I used a script recorder to record the steps to create a product however in the `HTTP Request` the parameters are set up with set values. I am able to change the `Width` and `Height` using a `CSV` Dataset but the values for the price appear to be hardcoded or set based on the script recorder. I can't figure out a way to have the price variables be dynamic and update based on the changes or recalculate when the width and height change. 
[image]

I need to have the price change based on the different width and height that the `CSV` brings in. The reason for the test is so that I can test that the pricing is working the same each time even after code change to the site are made. Any suggestions or example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most possibly the `ItemPrice` value is being **calculated** using client-side [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/jS/default.asp).

As per [JMeter project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So if my assumption is right and this `ItemPrice` comes from JavaScript you will not be able to trigger the changes by amending parameters.

1. Obtain somehow the algorithm of the price calculation depending on dimensions (look into page source, ask around, reach out to developers)
2. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the request
3. Implement your login in [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) even despite the fact JavaScript exists in the "language" dropdown
4. Replace recorded hard-coded price with the generated value